# Net Core: Best way to Hold a List of Image Url and Description

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a generic type in C# which holds a list of Image Url and image Title Description?  Otherwise I will create the following, just confirming their is no library function class for this.

```
 List<Tuple<string, string>>
```

Comment: How about using a `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: Why not creating a class? Anyway, this is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function/class for this. Use a Dictionary or a custom class. Custom class would allow better extensibility in future since you can just add additional fields to the class.